# Eclipse Neon: can't find my user-defined class (c++, Linux)

Tags: c++, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I have a c++ project in Eclipse Neon with Ubuntu 16.04 configured to use opencv. The project seemend to be correctly (i.e: opencv is not the issue :-) ) configured until I created a new class in the project and tried to use it from main.
[image: screenshot]

The IDE seems to know my class 'Calculaflujos' exists, as the autocomplete features displays a list of the class methods. However, when I try to build the project it says (lower part of screenshot): 'fatal error: Calculaflujos.cpp, no such file or directory'.

I have very little experience with c++ and the make file has been generated by Eclipse.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: PS, although you didn't ask, the `#ifndef INCLUDES` is a common pattern in C and C++ that should be in the header file. See [Include Guard Macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Include_Guard_Macro) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things going on here:

1. You should include the `.h` file from another `.cpp` file.
2. You are using `<>` type includes, which means it will not consider files in the current directory. Either use `""` or add `src` to your include path.

A concrete little example:

```
$ cat a.h
/* stuff in header file */

$ cat quotes.cc 
#include "a.h"

$ cat gtlt.cc 
#include <a.h>

$ g++ -c quotes.cc

$ g++ -c gtlt.cc
gtlt.cc:1:15: fatal error: a.h: No such file or directory
 #include <a.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.

$ g++ -c gtlt.cc -I .
```

3. Consider the output in the *Console* view. Sometimes seeing the raw output from the compiler makes sense. It is always very helpful to include that in a question like this too.

Comment: Your advice put me on the right direction, I found out I was also mixing class definition and implementation. Thank you!